# Stack draw toolbars with ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to stack two different geometry draw toolbars with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript namely a point and a polyline.

The goal is to create a point with the first click and simultaneously start the polyline draw mode so that the polyline start and the point overlie each other.

I created a sample which partially works but the last part of the polyline is not recognized and won't be drawn to the map:

[codepen sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrmzOz?editors=1000)

```
      map.on("load", createToolbar);

  function createToolbar(themap) {
    pointToolbar = new Draw(map);
    pointToolbar.on("draw-end", addToMap);
    polylineToolbar = new Draw(map);
    polylineToolbar.on("draw-end", addToMap);
  }

  on(dojo.byId('draw'), 'click', activateTool);

  function activateTool() {
    pointToolbar.activate(Draw["POINT"]);
    polylineToolbar.activate(Draw["POLYLINE"]);
  }

  function addToMap(evt) {
    var symbol;
    if (evt.geometry.type == "point") {
      pointToolbar.deactivate();
    } else if (evt.geometry.type == "polyline") {
      polylineToolbar.deactivate();
    }
    switch (evt.geometry.type) {
      case "point":
      case "multipoint":
        symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
        break;
      case "polyline":
        symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol();
        break;
      default:
        symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();
        break;
    }
    var graphic = new Graphic(evt.geometry, symbol);
    map.graphics.add(graphic);
```

Is this a bug because of not intended use in the ArcGIS API or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/46933199/820534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's a bug of not intended use and there is a way to fix this.

Intercept and insert in a var, the last geometry Point, which is the Point created when the user double-clicks. Then, add this Point to the path of the Polyline.

First, rename the event `draw-end` to `draw-complete`, as it's deprecated, according to the documentation https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/draw-amd.html#events

You can also write the geometry type on activation of the toolbar this way :

```
function activateTool() {
  pointToolbar.activate(Draw.POINT);
  polylineToolbar.activate(Draw.POLYLINE);
}
```

Now the interception of the last Point, on double-click :

```
var lastPoint;
on(map, 'dbl-click', function(e){
  lastPoint= e.mapPoint;
});
```

Finally, let's add it to the Polyline:

```
function addToMap(evt) {
  var symbol;
  var geometry = evt.geometry;
  switch (geometry.type) {
    case "point":
    case "multipoint":
      pointToolbar.deactivate();
      symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
      break;
    case "polyline":
      polylineToolbar.deactivate();
      geometry.insertPoint(0, geometry.paths[0].length, lastPoint);
      symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol();
      break;
    default:
      symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();
      break;
  }
  var graphic = new Graphic(geometry, symbol);
  map.graphics.add(graphic);
}
```